# Nuxt content alternative for vue 3 + vite?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, netlify-cms, ssg

I want to create simple blog with netlify cms and i have no idea is there any plugin with same purpose as nuxt content and with complete api in vue 3.

I look to [Vite Plugin MD](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-md), while it's a great plugin but i have not found same function in nuxt content like fetch.

Is there any plugin with same functionality as nuxt content for vue 3 + vite?

Answer (score 0):

[Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) is still the best alternative to use Vue3 + Vite.
It's made by a guy who is both in the Vue and Nuxt core team btw.

It has some markdown support, not 100% equivalent to Nuxt content but it's a start. Otherwise, you can always complete it with some homemade solution like [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark).